# Installing pecl on debian

Tags: php, debian, pecl

I'm trying to instal pecl_http on my server according to [manual](http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/04/how-to-use-the-pecl-http-pecl_http-extension-to-make-http-requests-from-php/) manual is for ubuntu, but `apt-cache search pecl_http` returned `php5-pecl-http` as pecl http packadge:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
sudo apt-get install php5-pecl-http
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev
```

in the end of `php.ini` added `extension=http.so`.
`http_get()` and func that I need `http_parse_headers()` says that func is undefined. What's the problem?

Answer (score 13):

It's probably too late but for others a solution is explained here : http://www.mkfoster.com/2009/01/04/how-to-install-a-php-pecl-extensionmodule-on-ubuntu/

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev
```

Then,

```
sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

Comment: If you are still receiving messages from this account: You actually can mark your own answer as the answer (with the checkmark below the vote-arrows). Especially if nobody else has answered your question it's standard to do so. A little reward for sharing the results of your research with the community.